# onSameUrlNavigation reload for specific route

Tags: angular

Is it possible to apply the

```
onSameUrlNavigation: reload
```

on only one specific route in Angular?

Answer (score 4):

Only onSameUrlNavigation: reload alone doesn't work in the component, using it after `shouldReuseRoute` works:

```
constructor(private router:Router){}

ngOnInit(){
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
    this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it by adding the following code into your that specific route component.

```
constructor(private router:Router){
}
ngOnInit(){
 this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
}
ngOnDestroy(){
 this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'ignore';
}
```

Comment: I tried it with ignore already before mentioning that it didn't work. Try it from your side